# Android App Promotional Graphics

Tags: android

I am looking for a picture of an android phone that I can overlay my apps screen shots in for promotional purposes. For iOS apps apple provided you with images to use for this purpose. Is there a similar set of images we can get somewhere on the Android side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not official images, but it's easy to find these images. E.g., I've used templates that I've found [here](http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/) (scroll down to the bottom of post).